# Writing and publishing a technical note about an R package

Tags: publications, journals, software

I prepared a developmental version of an R package specific to my field of study. Now I would like to encourage more people to use it and contribute code. My plan is to release a technical note describing the package in a field-specific journal. MATLAB is dominating my area of research so I don't think that usual R-specific channels (CRAN or The R Journal) would be appropriate to reach this scientific community.

However, I could not find R-specific guidelines to releasing technical notes about R packages. This relates not only to this particular journal but scientific journals in general.

To be precise, I would like to know:

- it is a common practice to write a technical note about a package that's only available on GitHub (no CRAN version yet)
- at what stage of development the package should be so that it can be
  written up as a technical note
- are there any guidelines to publishing technical notes about R packages

Can you think of any other considerations to keep in mind?

Thanks

*I am aware of the submission [guidelines](https://journal.r-project.org/share/author-guide.pdf) to The R Journal but I think that my package is not aimed at the general public and it's at a rather early stage of development.*

*This question was previously posted on StackOverflow but the moderators suggested that I post it here.*

Comment: This is a very specific question for a very specific software (R). Not sure whether Academia SE is the right place.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but the SO moderators closed the question and suggested I ask it here :/

Comment: Okay. As far as I know, [R packages can be distributed using GitHub](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486508-Building-Testing-and-Distributing-Packages). I assume, that publishing a technical note about a R package publicly available on GitHub should be no big deal.

Comment: You may find this list from the Software Sustainability Institute's page to be useful: [In which journals should I publish my software?](https://www.software.ac.uk/which-journals-should-i-publish-my-software). Also, are there any R-specific mailing lists, forums? It seems that your target audience may be well represented there.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog The author used R in the title, but the question could be made more general as follows: "Writing and publishing a technical note about an scientific software package"

Comment: What is your technical subfield? Journals such as [_Source Code for Biology and Medicine_](http://scfbm.biomedcentral.com/) exist for biology and medicine and similar journals probably exist your field as well.

Comment: My subfield is neuroscience and I have found a journal which is willing to accept the technical note. The question is what are the procedures for releasing a technical notes for R packages (if there are any specific ones). Alternatively, guidelines for releasing technical notes on any software package could be also useful.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to submit your package to CRAN before the technical note is published. It's really not difficult if you can follow instructions.

Comment: @Roland that's my plan. I wanted to do it after a bit more testing and adding a couple more functions. What would be the main benefit of submitting to CRAN in terms of publishing the technical note? Would it make a package look more established?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see the connection to academia.

Comment: @epo3 Yes and just plain easier to install. Many users don't have Rtools on their Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will need to do a bit of work to find the most appropriate journal for your field, but publishing an article about an R package is completely acceptable. In fact, "[An R package for reading EPANET files](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364815216302870)" by Eck was published in [Environmental Modelling & Software](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/13648152) which describes itself as follows,

> Environmental Modelling & Software publishes contributions, in the
>   form of research articles, reviews and short communications, on recent
>   advances in environmental modelling and/or software. The aim is to
>   improve our capacity to represent, understand, predict or manage the
>   behaviour of environmental systems at all practical scales, and to
>   communicate those improvements to a wide scientific and professional
>   audience.

Comment: Thanks. I do realise that it is possible to release a technical note about an R package. I even found some examples but I wasn't sure how the authors tackled the writing or at what stage of software development it was done. If the communal wisdom of SE won't help, then I'll try to contact the authors.

Comment: @epo3 I'm actually working on a manuscript for EM&S for a Java package that I'm development. Let me know if you want my contact information since it is likely a conversation for outside of the SE.